# Swagger is not working in server in flask-restx

Tags: nginx, flask, nginx-config, nginx-location, flask-restx

I've deployed my flask-backend server with `Nginx`. I can see my swagger documentation locally going `127.0.0.1:5000` also going to my server IP address and port number `server_ip:5000`. Can I see my API documentation just going my server domain name? http://example.com it gives me following errors. My nginx config is here

```
server{
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name example.com;

   root /project_root_folder;
   index swagger.json;

   location / {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$http_origin' always;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
   }
}
```

[image]